# Im not sure how to use strtok to separate tokens

Tags: c, string, token

I am messing around with C and want to try and do the following. so a User enters a date in the following format

```
Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10
```

and  I want to Use strtok to separate tokens and display output as follows,

```
Month: July
Day: 8
Year: 2017
Hour: 22
Minute: 14
Second: 10
```

I have this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//"Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10"

int main(void) {
    char date[6][20];
    char *order[] = {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second" };
    printf(" Example: Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10 \n Enter date seperated by commas in following format: \n");
    char text;
    scanf(" %s, &text");

    char* delims = " ,:";
    char* token = strtok(text,delims);
    char** label =  order;
    int r = 0;
    while (token){

        strcpy(date[r],token);
        printf("%-8s: %s\n ",*label,date[r]);
    token = strtok(NULL,delims);
    label++;
    r++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output when I run the code

Example: Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10
Enter date seperated by commas in following format:
Monday, August 1, 2012, 21:12:9

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

What Am I doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Did you consider searching this site for `strtok` to see some examples of it's use? Or reading the documentation for `strtok` (which you can easily find using your favorite internet search engine. SO isn' a free coding service.

Comment: Read the documentation for the library.  Or any of thousands of examples online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char *order[] = {"Day", "Month", "Date", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second"};
    char text[]  = "Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10";

    char* delims = " ,:";
    char* token = strtok(text, delims);
    char** label = order;

    while(token)
    {
        printf("%-8s: %s\n", *label, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delims);
        label++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 4176KB
Day     : Saturday
Month   : July
Date    : 8
Year    : 2017
Hour    : 22
Minute  : 14
Second  : 10
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I am a visual learner. Do you think you could explain the use of the pointers for example in char *order[]. Like I understand what pointers are just not when to use them exactly.

Comment: specifically why you use a double pointer in label