# Use Strtok to seperate tokens using 2d array

Tags: c, token

I am messing around with C and want to try and do the following off instructions given. I understand that using a 2-d array isn't necessary but since the instructions say so below It is non negotiable to do otherwise. so a User enters a date in the following format

```
Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10
```

and  I want to Use `strtok` to separate tokens and display output as follows,

```
Month: July
Day: 8
Year: 2017
Hour: 22
Minute: 14
Second: 10
```

I need to do this by Creating an array of strings (or a 2-D string) and copy the tokens such that s[0]=”July”, s[1]=”8” and s[5]=”10”. Use a for loop to display s[0] to s[5].
I have this so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//"Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10"

int main(void) {
    char date[8][20];
    char *order[] = {"Month", "Day", "Year", "Hour", "Minute", "Second" };
    printf(" Example: Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10 \n Enter date seperated by commas in following format: \n");
    char text[64];
    scanf(" %s, text");

    char* delims = " ,:";
    char* token = strtok(text,delims);
    char** label =  order;
    int r = 0;
    while (token){

        strcpy(date[r],token);
        if (!date[r][0]) continue;
        printf("%-8s: %s\n ",*label,date[r]);
    token = strtok(NULL,delims);
    label++;
    r++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is my output when I run the code

Example: Saturday, July 8, 2017, 22:14:10
Enter date seperated by commas in following format:
Monday, August 1, 2012, 21:12:9
Month   : éq(u
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

What Am I doing wrong. Please help!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216359/discussion-on-question-by-vicente-nunez-use-strtok-to-seperate-tokens-using-2d-a).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Im not sure how to use strtok to separate tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62480623/im-not-sure-how-to-use-strtok-to-separate-tokens)